# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'force' of undefined in d3.js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This code is working for d3.js version 2 however, I am getting an error for force in version 4 as, specified in the title. I tried looking into it but, I couldn't get any solution. Below is the script part of my code. I took reference from this link : http://bl.ocks.org/jose187/4733747

```
<script>
function colores_google(n) {
    var colores_g = ["yellow", "#dc3912", "#ff9900", "#109618", "#990099", "#0099c6", "#dd4477", "#66aa00", "#b82e2e", "#316395", "#994499", "#22aa99", "#aaaa11", "#6633cc", "#e67300", "#8b0707", "#651067", "#329262", "#5574a6", "#3b3eac"];
    return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
    }

    var width = 960,
        height = 800
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g");
     var force = d3.layout.force()
                   .gravity(.05)
                   .distance(400)
                   .charge(-100)
                   .size([width, height]);
      d3.json("graphFile.json", function(json) {
          force
              .nodes(json.nodes)
              .links(json.links)
              .start();

       var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                     .data(json.links)
                     .enter()
                       .append("line")
                       .attr("class", "link")
                       .style('stroke', 'grey')
                       .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.weight); });

         var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                       .data(json.nodes)
                       .enter()
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("class", "node")
                        .call(force.drag);

             node.append("circle")
                 .attr("r",function(d){
    return d.radius * 5;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d,i) { return colores_google(i); } );

     node.append("text")
         .attr("dx", 12)
         .attr("dy", ".35em")
         .style('color', 'darkOrange')
         .text(function(d) { return d.name });

     force.on("tick", function() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

           node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
             });
           node.on('mouseover', function(d) {
                link.style('opacity', function(l) {
                if (d === l.source || d === l.target)
                        return 1;
                else
                        return 0.1;
         });
       });
            node.on('mouseout', function() {
                 link.style('opacity', 1);
          });
       });
       </script>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. The changes made from v3 (not even v2) to v4 are huge, and well documented: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#forces-d3-force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v4, `d3.layout.[...]` no longer exists. There are extensive changes in v4 which will require you to pretty much rewrite your code almost from the ground up. [Here](https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/58b872b4f15a358c3a9822f5a285c5be) is a network graph example created with the v4 `forceSimulation`. You can use it instead of your current reference to build in v4. That being said, there's nothing particularly wrong with using d3 v2, and as the saying goes, *if it ain't broke, don't fix it*. You can opt to just use d3 v2.

Answer (score -1):

Creates a new simulation with the specified array of nodes and no forces. If nodes are not specified, it defaults to the empty array.

Use **d3.forceSimulation([nodes])**

[know more](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/main/src/simulation.js)